# Experiencing audio issues with wireless CarPlay and iOS 13.2.3

Tags: car-integration

Used to have CarPlay connected via USB in my old car, but the new one is fitted with Wifi connection. Ever since I upgraded to the latest version of iOS I have an issue where the audio skips half a second every now and then (Random intervals between 10 and 20 seconds). It worked fine before upgrading to the latest version of iOS in the new car as well.

Has anyone else experienced this (yet), and possibly found a solution?
Car make is Volkswagen, but not sure this is valuable.

Comment: Does it still do that when you connect via USB?  I have wired CarPlay and don't experience any skipping in 2 different cars.

Comment: I will give that a try @fsb! 
Also did actually notice today that enabling data transfer via eSim in my car actually improves this. Could it be that the phone connection was used to stream both audio, carplay and car info (traffic data etc.)? 
Anyways - will let you know how it turned out!